# How do I search a list of characters in a text

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have to search the non-English text in a text fields in Power Query. Several language has special characters which might be searchable in the text field and if found then is obvious those text field is Non-English text.

I've tried and works to find specific language characters like "é" or "ä" etc. But I know to use only the Conditional Column function search each character and if found it then gives "0" as value than later I am multiplying all conditional column and if it is 0 then is Non-English text if it is "1" then is English.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column13", "Custom É", each if Text.Contains([Text 1], "É") then 0 else if Text.Contains([Text 2], "É") then 0 else if Text.Contains([Text 3], "É") then 0 else 1)
```

Is there a solution to search a list of special characters in the text fields (e.g. "ÁáÉéÖöÜüäß") -> search > results "0" if found anyone in the text otherwise gives as output "1".

Answer (score 4):

You can use `List.ContainsAny` to check if a list contains any values from a second list.

Combine this with `Text.ToList` to split characters into a list, then you have something like:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Prior Step", "Contains Special Characters", each List.ContainsAny(Text.ToList([Values]),Text.ToList("ÁáÉéÖöÜüäß")), type logical)
```

Of course, this approach requires you to provide the list of "special" characters you wish to test for. You could flip this round, and specify the "English" characters:

```
#"English Characters" = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ,.:;", // include all characters you consider "English"
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Prior Step", "Contains Special Characters", each not List.ContainsAny(Text.ToList([Values]),List.Union({Text.ToList(#"English Characters"), Text.ToList(Text.Upper(#"English Characters"))})), type logical)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I think the opposite way is better, I means to find the not English characters, like Czech, Hungarian, Spanish etc characters. If I found one of them in the cell then I can mark as nor English and this is enough for me. I will tell it how I was success.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [Range,find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) command on how to search for characters in Excel. I would also use it on combination with [VBA Strings and ASCII](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/ascii-characters.htm) which is all the ASCII characters recognised by Excel

Comment: the question was looking for a Power Query solution, not VBA

Comment: Thanks I will check this solution as well, I will be back with my results